# Como fazer um button ficar bloqueado ao ser clicado?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Eu tenho dentro desse bootbox, dois botões, no primeiro que esta escrito "Enviar Relatorio de Erro" Eu queria que quando a pessoa clicasse ele mostrasse tipo um glyphicon indicando que esta processando o envio e impossibilitasse a pessoa de clicar de novo. Abaixo o meu código:

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Ajax_Teste")', function (response) {
                alert("getJson sucesso");
            }).fail(function (data) {
                bootbox.confirm({
                    message: "Não foi possível processar a sua requisição",
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            label: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Enviar o relatório de Erro.',

                            className: 'btn-success',
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            label: 'Não enviar',

                            className: 'btn-danger',
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (result) {
                        //aqui entrará meu código
                        if (result)
                            console.log("confirmou");
                        else
                            console.log("cancelou");
                    }

                })

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Eu sei que devo inserir isso aqui:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
            $(this).button('enviando');
        });   
    });
```

Mais como inserir isso ai nesse contexto?

Comment: coloque seu código html na pergunta

Comment: ai esta o código meu amigo, no javascript se escreve html da forma que esta acima

Comment: Amigo, quando vc clica no botão vc faz uma chamada ajax? se sim coloque o código aqui

Comment: sim, editei a pergunta, dê uma olhada

Comment: eu sei que devo utilizar isso aqui $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(this).button('enviando');
    });   
});
O problema é como inserir isso no bootbox

Comment: A solução funcionou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está o código. Assumi que você vai fazer o envio dos dados de erro para um script via ajax. Para fazer a animação do botão usei o `Font Awesome`. Note que na função de callback de sucesso do modal eu dei um `return false`, isso para que o modal não feche até que a chamada AJAX esteja completa. Para fechar o modal eu usei a função `bootbox.hideAll()`. Agora basta você customizar o código da forma que quiser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Ajax_Teste")', function(response) {
    alert("getJson sucesso");
  }).fail(function(data) {
    bootbox.confirm({
      message: "Não foi possível processar a sua requisição",
      buttons: {
        confirm: {
          label: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Enviar o relatório de Erro.',
          className: 'btn-success',
        },
        cancel: {
          label: 'Não enviar',
          className: 'btn-danger',
        }
      },
      callback: function(result) {
        //aqui entrará meu código
        if (result) {

          $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {
              relatoria: 'Meu relatório de erro'
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              console.log(data);
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
              $('.btn-success').prop("disabled", true);
              $('.btn-success').html("<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> Enviando");

            },
            complete: function() {
              $('.btn-success').prop("disabled", false);
              $('.btn-success').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span> Enviar o relatório de Erro.");
              bootbox.hideAll();
            }
          });
          return false;
        } else
          console.log("cancelou");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```